# Python ctypes ValueError - too many arguements?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to access a custom DLL using ctypes. There are several functions inside this DLL and all functions except this particular function work when called using the WinDLL call procedure.

I created a seperate Python function that essentially wraps around

```
s = ctypes.WinDLL(r'MyDLL.dll')

def setupOptions(window_area, MinimumRunTime, IGU_Flag, InnerPaneStopFlag,
                     mass_1, x_GlassFail_1, x_WinFail_1,
                     mass_2=0, x_GlassFail_2=0, x_WinFail_2=0, x_gap=0,
                     MaxSteps=10000, MaxNumCycles=2, supp_coeff=0.40528, 
                     FailVelocityFactor=1.0, P_atm=14.7,
                     time_step=0.01, z=0.2, InitialStaticLoad=0.0, 
                     x_initial_1=0.0, Initial_Velocity_1=0.0,
                     x_initial_2=0.0, Initial_Velocity_2=0.0):

# Flag identifying whether the window is an IGU or not
apiIGUFlag = c_long(IGU_Flag)
apiInnerPaneStopFlag = c_long(InnerPaneStopFlag) 

# Percentage of critical damping
z = c_double(z)

# Timestep (this can be increased - didn't spend the time to calculate it)
time_step = c_double(time_step)

# Initial Conditions
InitialStaticLoad = c_double(InitialStaticLoad)
x_initial_1 = c_double(x_initial_1)
Initial_Velocity_1 = c_double(Initial_Velocity_1)
x_initial_2 = c_double(x_initial_2)
Initial_Velocity_2 = c_double(Initial_Velocity_2)

# Failure Values
x_GlassFail_1 = c_double(x_GlassFail_1)
x_WinFail_1 = c_double(x_WinFail_1)
x_GlassFail_2 = c_double(x_GlassFail_2)
x_WinFail_2 = c_double(x_WinFail_2)

# Environment parameters
P_atm = c_double(P_atm)
FailVelocityFactor = c_double(FailVelocityFactor)
supp_coeff = c_double(supp_coeff)

# Other Parameters
window_area = c_double(window_area)
x_gap = c_double(x_gap)

# Model Parameters
apiMaxSteps = c_long(MaxSteps)
apiMaxNumCycles = c_long(MaxNumCycles)

mass_1 = c_double(mass_1)
mass_2 = c_double(mass_2)

MinimumRunTime = c_double(MinimumRunTime)

return s.api_SetupWindowOptions(apiIGUFlag, apiInnerPaneStopFlag, z, time_step, InitialStaticLoad, apiMaxSteps,
                                       apiMaxNumCycles, x_initial_1, Initial_Velocity_1, mass_1, x_GlassFail_1,
                                       x_WinFail_1, x_initial_2, Initial_Velocity_2, mass_2, x_GlassFail_2,
                                       x_WinFail_2, x_gap, window_area, supp_coeff, P_atm, FailVelocityFactor, MinimumRunTime)
```

Here is the function called:

```
area = 2040.0
xgap = 0.5
mass1 = 51.26
mass2 = 51.26
xGlassFail1 = 0.970
xGlassFail2 = 0.750
xWinFail1 = 0.970
xWinFail2 = 9.18
IGUFLAG = 1
minruntime = 52.0
ret = setupOptions(area, minruntime, IGUFLAG, IGUFLAG, mass1, xGlassFail1, xWinFail1, mass2, xGlassFail2, xWinFail2, xgap)
```

I get this error when I run the code:

```
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (8 bytes in excess)
```

Like I said, I have called several other functions in this DLL and not had any issues. I tried using CDLL and that causes issues as well (160 bytes short). Any help would be appreciated as I have looked at this all over and simply cannot see what the problem is.

Also here is the function call from the C++ header file:

```
MyDLL_API long _stdcall api_SetupWindowOptions(long nIsIGU, long nInnerPaneStopCriteriaOnly, double dCritDampingPercent, double dTimeStep, double dStaticLoad, long nMaxSteps, long nMaxNumCycles,
                                               double dInitialDisplacementInnerPane, double dInitialVelocityInnerPane, double dMassInnerPane,
                                               double dGlassFailDeflInnerPane, double dWinFailDeflInnerPane, double dInitialDisplacementOuterPane, double dInitialVelocityOuterPane,
                                               double dMassOuterPane, double dGlassFailDeflOuterPane, double dWinFailDeflOuterPane, double dGapSize, double dWindowArea,
                                               double dSupportCoefficient, double dAtmPressure, double dFailVelocityFactor, double dMinimumRuntime);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? It's a whole lot easier to just set `s.api_SetupWindowOptions.argtypes` than to write a wrapper function that manually wraps up each argument.

Comment: Also, did you write `MyDLL` yourself? If so… have you considered using a struct or two instead of 23 separate parameters?

Comment: Finally, are you sure the C++ header is right, and that the library (or, better, a simple C++ driver that _uses_ the library) compiles without warnings? Have you done a `#define _stdcall __stdcall` somewhere to make this work?